# QProcess exit status and starting new one

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qprocess

I'm a newbie in using QT

Code :

```
void MainWindow::test()
{
  ui->label->setText("it worked !");
  proc->start("c:/windows/system32/calc.exe");
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   proc = new QProcess();
   connect(proc,SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),this,SLOT(test()));
   proc->start("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe");
}
```

So it starts notepad when I close it, calc is started but it keeps opening infinitely.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: your `connect` will not work and your question is not clear ... please add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not disconnecting the slot, the moment "calc.exe" exits it will be launched again.

I.e. when notepad.exe finishes, the signal triggers the `test()` slot which runs "calc.exe".
When "calc.exec" finished, the very same series of events happens again.

Comment: Thanks i added this disconnect(proc,SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),this,SLOT(test())); to test function and it worked perfect. Just for curiousity am I using signal and slot in a wrong way ; is there any cleaner way to do it or is this fine?

Comment: Sounds ok. Alternatively you could check in `test()` which program has ended before launching calc.exe